# Fields should not accept only spaces

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In one of my forms, all input fields are allowing only whitespace characters to be submitted. This is also true for whitespace characters at both ends of the input.

The form is set up in HTML and has angular validators.

I want to check that:
only whitespace character should throw an error message. Also, check the input values for whitespaces at both ends.

Generic message to be shown: "Space not allowed at the start or end"

Any intuition would also help.

Comment: Are you up for something which allows you to disable spacebar on your field?

Comment: put your example html code and form component code please ?

Comment: @AshutoshKumar No, I don't think so.

Comment: @RohitDubey, in that case, you must use the Regex validator.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a built in regex pattern matching validator `Validators.pattern`.

Full docs here: https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern

I'm not great with regex, so you'll have to figure out the exact pattern you want on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator to handle this.

```
new FormControl(field.fieldValue || '', [Validators.required, this.noWhitespaceValidator])
```

Add noWhitespaceValidator method to your component

```
public noWhitespaceValidator(control: FormControl) {
    const isWhitespace = (control.value || '').trim().length === 0;
    const isValid = !isWhitespace;
    return isValid ? null : { 'whitespace': true };
}
```

and in the HTML

```
<div *ngIf="yourForm.hasError('whitespace')">Please enter valid data</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to check if a string starts with or ends with whitespace.

```
var re = /^\s|\s$/
if(str.match(re)){
   //starts with or ends with whitespace
}
```